# What is the difference between 사업 and 기업?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I understand them both as `enterprise` or `business`, but I am wondering about the difference and nuance and usage.

One question might be why are the big corporations called `대기업` and not `대사업`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`기업` usually means "groups" which aim to get profit like company, while `사업` means management or business. So, phrases like `그 기업이 하는 사업`, which means "The business carried out by the firm", is possible.

Since corporations are groups, "big corporations" is translated as `대기업`. `대사업` is more likely to be "big business".

Answer (score 3):

기업 is the organization/company/corporation. 사업 is the activity (i.e., what the organization *does*).

In English, *business* or *enterprise* can be used in both senses, which may be the source of confusion.